# Java - Double and Int Error

Tags: java

I have a Variable like this

```
int tff = 100;
double x = (45/100) * tff;
int y = (int) (tff - x);
System.out.println(y);
```

It's should be output 55, but why the output is 100?

Comment: Because 45/100 == 0.

Comment: you need to use `(45/100d) * tff;`, you need to identify at least one of the variables as double, otherwise it will be an intiger divison.

Comment: it is 0.45 .-., in php i can do that math, but in java , in confusing

Comment: @KevinEsche I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(45/100) = 0.45** when **(45/100)** is double and 
**(45/100) = 0** when **(45/100)** is integer.
So **(45/100)** should be cast to double as following:

```
double x = ((double)45/(double)100)* tff;
```

Comment: This will still not work. You first do integer division `(45/100)` which is `0` and then you cast that to `double`. The result will be a `double` with the value zero.

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify the values as the specific number type that they represent. You can notice it at many examples. A simple number without an identifier as `100d` or `100.0` for example will allways be handled as an integer.

You could use the identifier for the type after the number like this.

```
int tff = 100;
double x = (45/100d) * tff;
int y = (int) (tff - x);
System.out.println(y);
```

Other examples where you could need this identifier could be the long.

```
// This wont compile since it is out of the integer range
long l = 12312354345346;
// This will compile since it is declared to be a long
long l = 12312354345346l;
```

Answer (score 0):

`45` is `integer`, `100` is an `integer` so `45/100 == 0`

you can try using `45.0` and `100.0` instead

```
int tff = 100;
double x = (45.0/100.0) * tff;
int y = (int) (tff - x);
System.out.println(y);
```

alternatively you could cast the numbers as doubles:

```
double x = (((double)45)((double)/100)) * tff;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't cast it to a double first. You will get a int out of it. So your value wil be lower then '1', java thinks it is a zero. so wat you have to do:

```
int tff = 100;
int value1 = 45;
int value2 = 100;
double x = ((double)value1 / (double)value2) * tff;
int y = (int)(tff - x);
System.out.println(y);
```

Output will be: 55!